# Trajectory clustering - preprocessing and algorithms

Tags: time-series, clustering, spatial, spatio-temporal, dbscan

## Context

Consider the following problem where we have two time dependent (yearly) measures:

- Fertility rate
- Life expectancy

And a dimension: country. In other words we have over two hundred *"bivariate" time series*, one for each country.

This data can be plotted in a scatter plot for a single year (LHS) and animating the scatter plot over several years gives the following trajectory path (RHS). See [here](http://g.recordit.co/LLXAcB6YUO.gif) for the gif animation.

[image]

## Question

What **approaches, preprocessing steps and algorithms** can be used in order to cluster the trajectories of each country over time ? For example, a use case would be to find a cluster of countries for which the life expectancy falls abruptly (and against the overall trend) during the mid 90's. This is partly due to the AIDS epidemic in sub-saharan Africa at the time.

I am familiar with various clustering techniques for longitudinal data, but I struggle to understand how to transform this ordered data set into a format which can be fed into an algorithm.

## Some sources / ideas \ comments

The following SE posts offer some help

- [Trajectory Clustering: Which Clustering Method?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70106/trajectory-clustering-which-)
  clustering-method which suggests in a comment to use DTW on the data by using a polar transformation $r= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
- [how DBSCAN can be used with track data/trajectory data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263356/how-dbscan-can-be-used-with-track-data-trajectory-data) which suggests to compute a distance matrix using a suitable trajectory distance and run DBSCAN
- [Clustering of Vehicle Trajectories](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5462900/) which uses the Hausdorff distance but I am not sure how..

The blocking point in my understanding is that there are *ordered* sets of points, which means that using clustering algorithms on the *unordered* data may be miss leading. For example in the picture below

[image]

Trajectories are close together when un-ordered, but far when ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are aiming to explore two overlapping problems. *Preprocessing* time-trajectories and *clustering* time-trajectories.
Functional data analysis (FDA) and in particular the methodology behind Multivariate Functional Principal Components seems like a potential avenue for what you want.

In respect to preprocessing:

Dynamic Time Warping [1] is just one of the multiple and earliest (prior to 1980) ways of exploring the curve alignment problem. Of the top of my head I can think of "pairwise synchronization"[2] approaches, "quantile synchronisation"[3] approaches, "self-modelling warping functions"[4] approaches as well as "square-root velocity functions"[5] approaches. All these approaches try to align data registered over a continuous domain (most often than not, *time*).

In respect to clustering:

Clustering trajectories has been a task visited by multiple scientific communities. I would not confine my search to Statistics community; for example, Zheng [6] gives an excellent overview of what takes place on the Computer Science side of things. That said and turning back to FDA-based approaches, Jacques & Preda [7] offer a relatively nice overview of the matter. In general, most approaches take the approach "align, get relevant representation (i.e. one that encapsulate the function-like nature of the data and  does not treat the data as a simple multivariate sample) and then cluster". There is a smaller community with model-based approaches where alignment and clustering are done concurrently (e.g. [8]).
As mentioned it seems the data you are concerned with are multivariate (or more accurately bivariate) so probably approached related to multivariate functional principal components (e.g. [9]) would be helpful to get a relevant representation prior to clustering. (You may also find my answer here on :*[How to consider different samples in functional data clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212037/how-to-consider-different-samples-in-functional-data-clustering)* useful.)

Notice that earlier approaches like the DTW, focused on time-registration and generally regarded the amplitude changes as "not so important". That was a reasonable assumption for their working environment (e.g. Speech processing, later on vehicle trajectories) where difference in phases (i.e. *when* the amplitude of the function changed) are usually more important that difference in amplitude (i.e. *how much* the amplitude of function changed). For example, when doing phoneme registration we do not really care how loud the speaker talks or when we doing air-traffc registration we do not care a lot about a plane's cruising altitude. In contrast, biological/medical applications (e.g. how fast does a particular animal reach peak weight, and what that peak weight is) people often care about both.

For something quick out of the box I would suggest looking at the CRAN has a separate *view* on [Functional Data Analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/FunctionalData.html). There is a specific section of algorithms addressing the task of clustering functional data.

References:

1. H. Sakoe & S. Chiba. [Dynamic programming algorithm optimization for spoken word recognition](https://www.irit.fr/~Julien.Pinquier/Docs/TP_MABS/res/dtw-sakoe-chiba78.pdf). (1978) *IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech
   and Signal Processing*
2. R. Tang & H.-G. Mueller. [Pairwise curve synchronization for functional data](http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~mueller/warp102.pdf). (2008) *Biometrika*
3. Z. Zhang & H.-G. Mueller. [Functional density synchronization](http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~mueller/fdw16.pdf). (2011) *Computational Statistics and Data Analysis*
4. D.  Gervini  &  T.  Gasser. [Self-modelling  warping  functions](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/people.uwm.edu/dist/6/111/files/2016/04/B5582R3-1jdt7pc.pdf). (2004) *Journal  of  the  Royal  Statistical  Society.  Series  B*
5. S. Kurtek,  A. Srivastava,  &  W. Wu. [Signal  estimation  under  random  time-warpings  and  nonlinear  signal alignment](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4253-signal-estimation-under-random-time-warpings-and-nonlinear-signal-alignment.pdf). (2011) *Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems*
6. Y. Zheng. [Trajectory Data Mining: An Overview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/trajectory-data-mining-an-overview/). (2011) *ACM Transactions on Intelligent Systems and Technology*
7. J. Jacques & C. Preda. [Functional data clustering: a survey](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00771030/file/RR-8198.pdf). (2014) *Advances in Data Analysis and Classification*
8. E. Fu & N. Heckman. [Model-based curve registration via stochastic approximation EM algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07265.pdf). (2018) *Computational Statistics and Data Analysis* (to appear)
9. C. Happ & S. Greven. [Multivariate Functional Principal Component Analysis for Data Observed on Different (Dimensional) Domains](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07265.pdf). (2018) *Journal of the American Statistical Association*

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot for all these references. Let me know if you find something like a tutorial or worked example

Comment: Cool, I am happy I could help. I think you are a Pythonista right? Quickly checking for `Python "curve registration" example`, returned a Github repo named: [pyFDA](https://github.com/ptonner/pyFDA), I have not used it and I cannot intelligently comment on the correctness of it but it does contain a registration example you might want to check out. The Square Root Velocity stuff in Python can be found in [fdasrsf_python](https://github.com/jdtuck/fdasrsf_python); I have met the dev once in a conference, he seemed on top of what he was doing. Give it a spin!

Answer (score 1):

Well. You already found the answer three times...

Use a trajectory distance function such as DTW.
It solves the problem you mention quite well, because it doesn't ignore order.